# mouse in midnight commander works only under root

Tags: centos, terminal

[I posted a question a little time ago](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/55606/mouse-in-gnome-terminal) about mouse that doesn't work with terminal, and then I remarked that mouse works fine, but only under root. Can I change this behavior? It seems i need to *recompile* kernel to enable support mouse for ordinary users in terminal, how to do this?

Comment: Where did you found information about kernel recompilation?

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for mouse functionality with a VIM editor in Linux, then you should try:

```
:set mouse=a
```

This will enable mouse support for your text file and you can scroll up & down traversing your file or can point any line or text in the file.

It applies for every user.

Comment: Mansab, i'm not looking for VIM or terminal copy-paste, but for Midnight Commander support mouse.